# Failed for Watchdata check in Linux - java.security.KeyStoreException: PKCS11 not found

Tags: java, linux, ubuntu, cryptography, pkcs#11

I am trying to install and use the EMSigner app from the GST Portal on a linux machine.

Ref:

1. https://www.gst.gov.in/help/docsigner
2. https://www.gst.gov.in/system/#/sysreq-install-steps

While signing the website asks for the token key password, and after entering the password it fails with a message, "unable to load token"

Looking into the console log for emsigner I see the following error message

```
                                                                                                             
library =/usr/lib/WatchData/eMudhra_3.4.3/lib/libwdpkcs_eMudhra_343.so                                                                                                   
Failed for Watchdata check in Linux - java.security.KeyStoreException: PKCS11 not found                                                                                  
error msg==>>PKCS11 not found                                                                                                                                            
check==>>PKCS11 not found
```

I am not sure what needs to be done for the S/W to find PKCS11.

My configuration is:

```
java -version
java version "1.8.0_261"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_261-b12)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.261-b12, mixed mode)

lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Linuxmint
Description:    Linux Mint 20
Release:        20
Codename:       ulyana
```

My Hardware token is proxkey

Answer (score 1):

i have a similar case.
the watchdata token used by the brazillian government is slightly different from yours, but i got it working with:

## required for watchdata token

- these packages

```
apt install dkms libnss3-tools
```

## web browser config

- chrome web browser (replace with the path to your library)

```
modutil -dbdir sql:.pki/nssdb/ -add "token-watchdata" -libfile /usr/lib/watchdata/ICP/lib/libwdpkcs_icp.so
```

- mozilla based web browser like firefox and  palemoon (use the path to your library)

[image: mozilla-load-pkcs11-module]

## optional java support

- if you also need java support, it will only work on palemoon (or very old firefox releases).
- search on the internet for a file called `libnpjp2.so` and place it on `/usr/lib/mozilla/plugins/`

```
~:$ ls /usr/lib/mozilla/plugins/

libnpjp2.so
```

you also will need java packages

```
apt install default-jdk openjdk-11-jdk
```

```
~:$ java -version

openjdk version "11.0.8" 2020-07-14
```

and thats it. java + token module working on palemoon.
chrome doesnt support java, but will load the pkcs11 module.

Comment: In india the setup is slightly different. We have a java application called emsigner which opens port 1585 on local host. This application is responsible for communicating with the proxykey token, and signing the webpage.
The GST Webpage communicates with this application via port 1585

The error message I received is from this application and not the browser.

I have installed dkms and libnss3-tools. It did not fix the problem.

Comment: Thanks @BharatVasant, Does this also support the MCA Portal?

Comment: @vijayvithal: The extension has PKCS1 raw signature as well as CMS signature. You may provide us link for signature specifications. (We add api or features, free on merit basis or charge very small fees to client and the feature becomes available to all, free to charge.)  Upvote the answer at the above link if useful :)